# ssrs dynamic value in text box and title

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services

I have a report which runs weekly and in one of the tables it says week1, week2 etc all the way to the recent week (e.g. week28 currently)

This table is in the report and I would like the week28 value to be in the title. The title reads "summary report for" I want to place the week number at the end so every week the report is run it changes.

There are also a couple of other places I would like to place the dynamic value but i'm guessing the code will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a sorted dataset called "MyDataset" with a column that contains the week names called "Week", you could simply use the following expression:

```
=Last(Fields!Week.Value, "MyDataset")
```

This returns the last value in the Week column of MyDataset.

Alternatively, you could construct the week number using some of the date functions, for example the [`datepart` function](http://rpelepei.blogspot.no/2011/02/datepart-function-in-ssrs.html)

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to get away with `=Max(Fields!Week.Value, "MyDataSet")`

Comment: `Max` only works when the Week field is numeric, or if it is a string, that the week numbers have been prepended with zeros. Otherwise, "Week 9" will be larger than "Week 19".